# Как отослать большие файлы?

Tags: сеть, сокеты, delphi, отправка, сокет

У меня есть `c:\test.txt = 300мб`. Передача `TcpClient` и `TcpServer`.
Не шлются большие файлы!

Существующий 100% рабочий код для маленьких файлов:

```
procedure TForm1.Button3Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fileName: WideString;
  fileSize: Int64;
  dataFile: PByte;
  hFile: File;
begin
  if TcpClient1.Connect then
  begin
    TcpClient1.Sendln('dlmain');

    fileName := TcpClient1.Receiveln();
    fileSize := StrToInt64(TcpClient1.Receiveln());
    dataFile := AllocMem(fileSize);
    try
      TcpClient1.ReceiveBuf(dataFile^, fileSize);

      if SaveDialog1.Execute(Handle) then
      begin
        AssignFile(hFile, SaveDialog1.fileName);

        Rewrite(hFile, 1);
        BlockWrite(hFile, dataFile^, fileSize);
        CloseFile(hFile);
      end;
    finally
      FreeMem(dataFile);
    end;

    TcpClient1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TcpServer1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TcpServer1.Active := False;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
  S: string;
  f: file of byte;
  fs, fn: string;
  mem: TmemoryStream;
  fStream: TFileStream;
begin

end;

procedure TForm1.TcpServer1Accept(Sender: TObject;
  ClientSocket: TCustomIpClient);
var
  msg: WideString;
  hFile: TFileStream;
  fileName: WideString;
begin
  fileName := 'C:\test.txt';
  msg := ClientSocket.Receiveln();

  if msg = 'dlmain' then
  begin
    hFile := TFileStream.Create(fileName, fmOpenRead);
    try
      ClientSocket.Sendln(fileName);
      ClientSocket.Sendln(IntToStr(hFile.Size));
      ClientSocket.SendStream(hFile);
    finally
      hFile.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Не забывайте форматировать код кнопкой `101010`.

Comment: ? поясните! Что за 101010 ?

Comment: 0_О это в дельфе или тут ?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, исходник клиента.

Comment: @SWNTFZ вопросу четыре года, вряд ли автор что-то сможет добавить.

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле все отсылается: и маленького размера файлы, и большого. Просто времени для передачи "больших" файлов требуется больше, да и сетевого трафика тоже...В связи с этим, создается впечатление, что приложение зависло, ведь так? На самом же деле это только "иллюзия" - основной поток переключил всю свою "мощь" =) на другое задание. Вам следует использовать многопоточность в своем приложении. Основной поток будет занят, непосредственно, самим приложением, а вспомогательный, который вы создадите - отправкой файла. В дельфи это очень просто!

Answer (score 0):

[[@kindoskin](/users/7988/kindoskin)](/users/7988/kindoskin), посылай файл кусками. Например, размером в 1024 байт.

Comment: я буду крайте признателен если будет демо.zip :))) или хотя бы код. юзаю xe2.